Keycloak's Impersonate the user API is not working
I am trying to use Keycloak's Impersonate the User API to allow a 'customer admin' to impersonate another user. However, I am facing issues with the API where it does not work as expected.
What I've Done:

Assigned Impersonation Role: I have assigned the Impersonation role to the 'customer admin'.

API Call Configuration: I'm calling the impersonation API with the following Angular code:



const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('access_token')}`
});
return this.http.post(
  `${base-url}/admin/realms/realm-name/users/${userId}/impersonation`,
  {}, { headers }
);




Keycloak Client Configuration: I have configured my Keycloak client (account-console) and added the redirect URI ({base-url}/realms/{realm-name}/account) to the "Valid Redirect URIs" field.

Response from API Call: When I make this call, I get the following response:
{
"redirect": "{base-url}/realms/{realm-name}/account",
"sameRealm": true
}

This redirect uri takes me to this page:



Issue:
When I follow the redirect URL provided in the response, it leads to a sign-in page instead of directly logging me into the impersonated user's session. If I sign in on that page with the 'customer admin' credentials, it redirects to an account management page, which only has features for managing the account, not impersonating another user.

Questions:

Why is the impersonation not proceeding directly to the impersonated user's session?
Is there any additional configuration required in Keycloak to make the impersonation work seamlessly?
Could this be related to how the session or cookies are being handled, or perhaps a misconfiguration in the realm settings or client settings?

Any insights or advice on how to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated. I am particularly interested in knowing if there are specific settings or configurations in Keycloak that I might be missing.
